# Azure SQL Server rejects all connections

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a SQL server instance on Azure. It rejects all connections with the following error:

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=430; handshake=29567;  (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

This is not a firewall issue as I currently have the following rule in place:
Allow All 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255

Here is my connection string (username and password fuzzed):

```
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "resiserver.database.windows.net";
    builder.UserID = "username";
    builder.Password = "password";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "resiDB";
    ConnectionString  = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Can this link  https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/connection-timeout-expired-pre-login-handshake/ be helpful for you?

Comment: Not a lot to go on here. Depending on the connection string there can be multiple requirements for firewall access, services configuration and service enablement. Can you edit your question to show us your connection string (use fake servername, username, password of course)? Otherwise it could be something to do with the phase of the moon.

Comment: Unfortunately not, though it confirmed my server is listening on port 1433.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've added my connection details

Comment: Can you connect using a SQL tool such as Azure Data Studio or SQL Server Management Studio? Are you on a corporate network? Sometimes outgoing connection are blocked on the corporate network.